# Using tablemodel in EDT which generated by SwingWorker

Tags: java, jtable, swingworker, tablemodel

I have Swingworker for create table model for update the jTable when program is launched. But i dont know how can i call this model from EDT and apply this model to my jtable ?

Here my Swingworker code;

```
public class FillTable extends SwingWorker<DefaultTableModel, DefaultTableModel> {
    private final DefaultTableModel model;
    public FillTable(DefaultTableModel model) {
     this.model = model;
    }

   @Override
 protected DefaultTableModel doInBackground() throws Exception {
        ResultSet rsaccounts;
        Statement stmt;
        String queryaccounts = "select NAME from acc (nolock)\n" + "order by Name";

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.100.100.23;" + "databaseName=Dbacc;" + "user=" + "sa" + ";" + "password=" + "sapassword!" + ";"; 
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rsaccounts = stmt.executeQuery(queryaccounts);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rsaccounts.getMetaData();


        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        columnNames.add(rsmd.getColumnName(1)); 
        System.out.println(columnNames);
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

       while (rsaccounts.next()) {
            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            vector.add(rsaccounts.getObject(columnIndex));
            }
            data.add(vector);
       }

        rsaccounts.close();
        stmt.close();
        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        return model;
    }


  protected void done() {
    try {
        TableModel model = get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Below method return error;
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set a null TableModel

```
private DefaultTableModel model1;

FillTable fff = new FillTable(model1);
        fff.execute();
        model1 = fff.model;

        jTable3.setModel(model1);
```

Comment: You could also simply have asked me to explain my answer in greater detail when i replied to your previous post that you should update yout table from done() which runs on the EDT. You didn't even upvote my answer which brought your attention to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are executing something like

```
FillTable fff = new FillTable(model1);
fff.execute();
model1 = fff.model;
jTable3.setModel(model1);
```

then the line `model1 = fff.model` will most likely be executed *before* the SwingWorker has finished. The `execute` call will cause the work to be done *in the background*, and the next lines well be executed regardless of whether the work already finished or not.

A general approach could be to use the model in your `done()` method, *roughly* like this:

```
protected void done() {
    try {
        TableModel model = get();

        jTable3.setModel(model); // Use it here!

    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

(You'll have to pass a reference of `jTable3` to your SwingWorker for this - that is, pass it to the constructor and store it as a field in the SwingWorker).

There may be more elegant solutions, but based on the code that was provided so far, this at least seems to be the *reason* for the error and a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is worked. But i wonder; Can i use created table model from EDT not in Swingworker ?

Comment: The question is not clear to me. The TableModel is created in "doInBackground", and the "done()" method is called (on the EDT) when the creation of the TableModel is finished.

Comment: Oh my answer is: ""done()" method is called (on the EDT)" thanks.

Comment: +1. I've deleted my answer because yours already covers what I've said. Well done!

Comment: @dic19 Not sure whether that was necessary. What you said was correct as well. But to avoid confusion, I removed the (now invalid) link from my answer.

Comment: @dic19 Thanks for remind me about important line model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames); Also i have edited my question now.